# Loading two SQL columns into a listview but only need to display the first column Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am using an sqllite database to store two columns which are phonename and phonenumber. I am using an arrayList to iterate through the data and display the phonename in a listview which is working, but I also need to iterate through the phonenumber column under the same listview as well. I only need the phonename to be showing in the listview.

This is for when the user has selected the item in the listview, it shows the selected phonename and phonenumber, which at the moment it is only currently showing the phonename and showing blank for phonenumber for obvious reasons.

**DataDBAdapter**

```
public long insert(String phonename, String phonenumber)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME,phonename);
    cv.put(COL_MYTABLE_PHONENUMBER,phonenumber);

    return mDB.insert(TBL_MYTABLE,null,cv);
}

    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Iterating through the database
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public ArrayList<String> getAllRowsAsList()
    {
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_MYTABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<>();
        while (csr.moveToNext())
        {
            rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME)));
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

**SelectModemFragment**

```
 private void manageListView(Context context)
    {
        thelist = dbHelper.getAllRowsAsList();  // Extract the list, just the phone names

        // Only setup the adapter and the ListView if the adapter hasn't been setup
        if(arrayAdapter == null)
        {
            // Instantiate the adapter
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,thelist); //<<<<<<<<<< list included
            display_contacts1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //<<<<<<<<<< Tie the adpater to the ListView

            // Set the ListViews OnItemClick Listener
            display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    String namedisplay = arrayAdapter.getItem(position); //<<<<<<<<<< this gets the phone name

                    namedisplay = arrayAdapter.getItem(position);

                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), namedisplay + " Selected for Communication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

using ArrayAdapter only allows a a single item to be passed, thus unless you resort to complicated/messy/inefficient methods ArrayAdapter is only really suitable for a single value.

## Fix

You could use an ArrayList where your_object has members for all the required values. i.e phonenumber and phonename. Noting that unless you use a Custom Adapter that you should override the the **toString** method to extract the data that you want to be displayed, as that is what a standard ArrayAdapter uses.

## Alternative (use a CursorAdapter)

An alternative would be to use a Cursor Adapter (e.g. SimpleCursorAdapter), you can then return the Cursor and use it directly. However, a CursorAdapter REQUIRES a column specifically name **_id** (BaseColumns._ID can be used).

One of the clear advantages of a Cursor adapter is the the 4th paremmter passed to the onItemClick/onItemLongClick is the **id** of the row (if used correctly) allowing a single value to then get/update/delete/pass the respective selected row.

- As such I'd recommend a Cursor Adapter for a ListView and hence the more comprehensive answer.

You may think I don;t have such a column. However, you can use the normally hidden **rowid** column and dynamically create a column named _id.

You could have a method, in the database helper (DataDBAdapter) such as :-

```
public Cursor getAllRowsAsCursor()
{
    String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID,"*"}
    return = mDB.query(TBL_MYTABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null)
}
```

The ManageList method could then be :-

```
private void manageListView(Context context) {

    myCursor = dbhelper.getAllRowsAsCursor();

    // Only setup the adapter and the ListView if the adapter hasn't been setup
    if(arrayAdapter == null)
    {
        // Instantiate the adapter
        arrayAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,myCursor,new String[]{DataAdapter.COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME},newint[]{android.R.id.text1},0);
        display_contacts1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //<<<<<<<<<< Tie the adpater to the ListView

        // Set the ListViews OnItemClick Listener
        display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String namedisplay = arrayAdapter.getItem(position); //<<<<<<<<<< this gets the phone name

                String phonenumber = myCursor,getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(DataAdapter.COL_MYTABLE_PHONENUMBER);

                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), namedisplay + " Selected for Communication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), phonenumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    } else {
        arrayAdapter.swapCursor(myCursor);
    }
```

## Notes

- MyCursor would be declared as a class variable e.g. `Cursor MyCursor;`
- Instaed of

  - `ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;` you would have
  - `SimpleCursorAdapter arrayAdapter;`
- ***The above is in-principle code and has not been tested, so there may be errors and/or omissions.***

## Working Example

The following is the code based upon the code from the previous question asked (which this appears to follow on from). It has two ListViews the old and a new one that uses a SimpleCursorAdapter. Clicking an item display phone number and also id. Lon Clicking an Item deletes that item (refreshing both ListViews).

**DataDBAdapter.java** has two new methods (so add these) :-

```
//<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
public Cursor getAllRowsAsCursor() {
    return mDB.query(TBL_MYTABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}

public int delete(long id) {
    String whereclause = COL_MYTABLE_ID + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    return mDB.delete(TBL_MYTABLE,whereclause,whereargs);
}
```

**SelectModemFragment.java** is now :-

```
public class SelectModemFragment extends Fragment {

    private SelectModemViewModel mViewModel;
    ListView display_contacts1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> thelist;
    DataDBAdapter dbhelper;

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    ListView display_contacts2;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;
    Cursor MyCursor;

    public static SelectModemFragment newInstance() {
        return new SelectModemFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_modem_fragment, container, false);
        display_contacts1 = view.findViewById(R.id.lv001); //<<<<<<<<<< top listview ArrayAdapter<String>
        display_contacts2 = view.findViewById(R.id.lv002);

        dbhelper = new DataDBAdapter(view.getContext());
        AddSomeData();
        manageListView(view.getContext());
        manageListView2();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SelectModemViewModel.class);
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }

    //Sets up the ListView if not already setup
    private void manageListView(Context context) {
        thelist = dbhelper.getAllRowsAsList(); //<<<<<<<<<< extract the list (just the phone names) from the database

        // Only setup the adapter and the ListView if the adapter hasn't been setup
        if (arrayAdapter == null) {
            // Instantiate the adapter
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,thelist); //<<<<<<<<<< list included
            display_contacts1.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); //<<<<<<<<<< Tie the adpater to the ListView

            // Set the ListViews OnItemClick Listener
            display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String name = arrayAdapter.getItem(position); //<<<<<<<<<< this gets the phone name
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"You clicked the phone named " + name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            //<<<<<<<<<< MODIFIED to cope with changes (needs to rebuild the array within the adpater)
            arrayAdapter.clear();
            for (String s: thelist) {
                arrayAdapter.add(s);
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED FOR CursorAdapter
    private void manageListView2() {
        MyCursor = dbhelper.getAllRowsAsCursor();
        if (sca == null) {
            sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    MyCursor,
                    new String[]{DataDBAdapter.COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            display_contacts2.setAdapter(sca);
            display_contacts2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                            "You Clicked the phone name " +
                                    MyCursor.getString(MyCursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME)) +
                                    ". The phonenumber is " +
                                    MyCursor.getString(MyCursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.COL_MYTABLE_PHONENUMBER)) +
                                    ". The ID (as passed) is " + String.valueOf(id) +
                                    ". The ID (from Cursor) is " + String.valueOf(MyCursor.getLong(MyCursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.COL_MYTABLE_ID)))
                            ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //<<<<<<<<<< EXTRA delete row on long click
            display_contacts2.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    dbhelper.delete(id);
                    manageListView2();
                    manageListView(getContext());
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } else {
            sca.swapCursor(MyCursor);
        }
    }

    // Add some testing data (only if none already exists)
    private void AddSomeData() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(dbhelper.getWritableDatabase(),DataDBAdapter.TBL_MYTABLE) < 1) {
            dbhelper.insert("Phone 1", "0000000000");
            dbhelper.insert("Phone 2", "1111111111");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        manageListView2();
        manageListView(getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        MyCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SahilBora That's because of a typo myCursor should be MyCursor. P.S. didn;t realise the code was from an answer of mine. Am about to edit the question with an example of both i.e. two separate ListViews (ArrayAdapter<String> and CursorAdapter). The latter also has long click to delete a row and refresh both lists.

Comment: It's all good, I got the code working just now. I've marked the answer as correct :)