# Listview always shows as empty with item selected Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a listview that has values loaded in from my sqlite database which I was getting help with from this question that I posted, [Loading two SQL columns into a listview but only need to display the first column Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388519/loading-two-sql-columns-into-a-listview-but-only-need-to-display-the-first-colum/55388960?noredirect=1#comment97500231_55388960)

When the user clicks on the item, it shows the name and phone number selected with the toast display, but on the Commands fragment, where I want to show which name has been selected, it is always defaulting to showing that listview is empty, even when I've clicked on an item in the listview to be selected for communication. I want to display the name selected on that textview which is not working.

**SelectModemFragment.java**

```
public static String SelectedName = null;
public static String SelectedPhNo = null;

display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    //String namedisplay = arrayAdapter.getItem(position); //<<<<<<<<<< this gets the phone name
                    String namedisplay = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.COl_MYTABLE_PHONENAME));
                    String phoneno_display = myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.COL_MYTABLE_PHONENUMBER));

                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), namedisplay + " Selected for Communication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), phoneno_display, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // Set the selected contact variables
                    SelectedName = namedisplay;
                    SelectedPhNo = phoneno_display;
                }
             });
```

**CommandsFragment.java**

```
     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_commands_view, container, false);

            if(SelectModemFragment.display_contacts.isEmpty() )
            {
                SelectedPhNo = null;

                // No contacts selected from the Add Modem listview
                modemView.setText("No contact selected");
            }
            else
            {
                modemView.setText(SelectedName);
            }

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: rather than using "static" variable, use Interface to communicate between fragments. kindly check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036572/how-to-pass-values-between-fragments

Comment: I have two separate fragments with their own activity screen. I've seen that page before but I feel that they are making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: from where do you call commands fragment ?

Comment: CommandsFragment is the name of the java class file